# PerfMon metrics collector graph shows the information upto 4mins but actual time of script execution is 10 mins

Tags: jmeter, perfmon

Need bit clarification in this PerfMon metrics collector have run the script for 10 mins and I am able to see the graph in PerfMon is only 4 mins refer screenshot for more details.

This I am trying to achieve by running the script with non GUI mode.

[image: This is image description]

Please suggest how to get correct graph of full 10 mins execution details.

Answer (score 0):

PerfMon Metrics Collector is a normal JMeter [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) so it should collect information from the [Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent) as long as [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) notifies it about finishing its work.

I can think of 2 possible reasons:

1. Incorrect placement of the PerfMon Metrics Collector listener. It obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) therefore if you add it to one Thread Group - it will only "listen" for the samplers in this Thread Group so if there are other Thread Groups in your test which run sequentially - they will not be a part of the telemetry
2. Aforementioned Server Agent was shut down after 4 minutes

Going forward consider including snapshot of your test plan, first and last couple of lines of the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) for JMeter and PerfMon, [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file and whatever else can help to get to the bottom of the issue.